# DB2 hang when query or opening large table

Tags: db2

I have a problem here. I have a DB2 v8.1 where I have this particular table which I cannot query or open. Whenever I tried to query or sample data it will tell me its a timeout/deadlock issue after for long time. No one is using the table so it cant be deadlock. Is there anyway i can recover this table? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Can you just do a select with an `UNCOMMITED READ` isolation level in order to bypass all the eventual locks :

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
WITH UR
```

This way it will retrieve 10 rows from the table. If it works, just do it again without the `FETCH FIRST` clause : it was effectively locked by some other connection.

You can also try with [changing the optimisation level](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0001007.htm) by issuing

```
SET CURRENT QUERY OPTIMIZATION 0
```

in order to just activate `INDEX SCAN`, `FULL SCAN` & `NESTED LOOPS` without all those efficient, but often expensive `HASH JOIN` & friends that could be the culprit here if the stats are miscalculated.

**Edit**:

With the comments, I think that your best bet would be with [db2dart](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0003477.htm) to check your database.

Comment: Hi there this is the error that I got when executing it.

DBA2191E SQL execution error.

com.ibm.db.DataException: A 
database manager error occurred. : [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] 
SQL0911N  The current transaction has been rolled back because 
of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "68".  SQLSTATE=40001

Comment: "68" means timeout & "2" means deadlock. (mnemonic : 68 > 2 & "timeout" > "deadlock")

Comment: Could you try with a "FOR READ ONLY" at the end of the request ?

Comment: Hmmm... Stop/start the DB ? BTW, what is you lock_timeout configuration value ?

Comment: i think I tried before stop and start still the same. how do you go to the lock_timeout config value? thanks for the help

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000329.htm

Comment: Is it possible my table is corrupted? I cannot even export the table. as I can see the exported file but its 0 bytes. :(

Comment: This is my error msg

SQL0911N  The current transaction has been rolled back because of 
a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "".

Explanation: 
The current unit of work was involved in an unresolved contention 
for use of an object and had to be rolled back.  

 The reason codes are as follows: 
 

 2 transaction rolled back due to deadlock.  

 68 transaction rolled back due to lock timeout.  

 72 transaction rolled back due to an error concerning a DB2 Data 
Links Manager involved in the transaction.  

Note: The changes associated with the unit of work must be     
       entered again.

Comment: (cont)
 The application is rolled back to the previous COMMIT.  

User Response: 

To help avoid deadlock or lock timeout, issue frequent COMMIT 
operations, if possible, for a long-running application, or for 
an application likely to encounter a deadlock.

Comment: Federated system users: the deadlock can occur at the federated 
server or at the data source.  There is no mechanism to detect 
deadlocks that span data sources and potentially the federated 
system.  It is possible to identify the data source failing the 
request

Deadlocks are often normal or expected while processing certain 
combinations of SQL statements.  It is recommended that you 
design applications to avoid deadlocks to the extent possible. 
 
sqlcode :  -911 
sqlstate :  40001